# Is this proof of product $f_n g_n \to fg$ in measure correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

[Edited after Bungo's comment]

$\mu(X) \lt \infty$ and $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ each in measure. Prove that $f_n g_n \to fg$, also in measure.

This is my attempt. Doesn't appear anywhere I have checked.

We want: $$\mu(E) = \mu(\{x:|f_n g_n - fg| \gt 2\epsilon \}) \to 0, \ \  n \to \infty $$

We know: $$E \subset \{x:|f_n|| g_n - g| \gt \epsilon \} \cup \{x:|g| |f_n - f| \gt \epsilon \}$$

Define $A:= \{x:|f_n|| g_n - g| \gt \epsilon \}$ and $B:=\{x:|g| |f_n - f| \gt \epsilon \}$

Thus: $E \subset A \cup B$

Rearranging algebraically, $A = \{x:| g_n - g| \gt \frac{\epsilon}{|f_n|} \}$.  By the Archimedean property $\exists r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ (can restrict to $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ since $\epsilon \gt 0$) such that: $$|g_n - g| \gt r \gt \frac{\epsilon}{|f_n|}$$

Thus: $$A = \bigcup_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} [ \{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_k \} \cap \{x:|f_n| \gt \frac{\epsilon}{r_k} \} ]$$

Notice: $$A \subset \bigcup_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} [ \{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_k \}=C$$

Similarly: $$B = \{x:|f_n - f| \gt \frac{\epsilon}{|g|}\} =  \bigcup_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} [ \{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_k \} \cap \{x:|g| \gt \frac{\epsilon}{r_k} \} ]$$

where $$B \subset \bigcup_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} [ \{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_k \}=D$$

Thus: 
$$ \mu(E) \le \mu(A) + \mu(B) \le \mu(C) +\mu(D)$$ $$\le \sum_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}} \mu(\{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_k \}) + \sum_{r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}}\mu(\{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_k \}) $$

$$= [\mu(\{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_1 \})+ \mu(\{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_2 \}) + \mu(\{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_3 \}) + ...]$$ $$+$$ $$[\mu(\{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_1 \})+ \mu(\{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_2 \})+ \mu(\{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_3 \})+... ] $$

Now since the given functions converge in measure, as $n \to \infty$, $\forall r_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ we have $\lim_n \mu(\{x:| g_n - g| \gt r_k \}) = 0$ and $\lim_n \mu(\{x:|f_n - f| \gt r_k \}) = 0$

Thus: as $n \to \infty$, 
$$\mu(E) \to 0. $$ Thus, $f_n g_n \to fg$ in measure.

Comment: It seems that you are implicitly arguing that you can interchange the limit and sum in $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r \in \mathbb Q} \mu(\{x : |g_n - g| > r\})$ and in $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r \in \mathbb Q} \mu(\{x : |f_n - f| > r\})$. How do you justify this? Aren't both sums infinite for any fixed $n$? If $r$ is negative then $\{x : |g_n - g| > r\}$ is all of $X$. So each sum includes infinitely many occurrences of $\mu(X)$.

Comment: @Bungo In the original invocation of the Archimedean property, since $\epsilon \gt 0$, I believe I can restrict the $r$ to $r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}.$ Then, I don't think your point should be problem any more.

Comment: Even with that modification, I don't think it's valid. What if $g_n = 1/n$ (the constant function) and $g = 0$? Then for fixed $n$, the set$\{x : |g_n - g| > r\}$ is all of $X$ for infinitely many positive rational values of $r$.